# Android Activity Handling (Resume/Restart)

Tags: android, navigation, android-activity, xamarin.android

I hope you can help me understanding the Android Lifecycle and how I can manage navigation between several kinds if activities. Suppose the following scenario:

- Activity A "MainMenu" is started: User clicks on a menuentry
- Activity B is started and UI is loaded with content from local database
- user interacts with Activity B
- user presses Backbutton and returns to Activity A
- user presses again the same menuentry for returning to activity B
- At the moment: The activity is loaded from scratch
- Whished: The previous instance of Activity B with all its UI entries and User interactions should resume

I thought of saving all activities in a static manager. If a activity is started, the manager looks if it has already been started previously. If so, resume the previous activity else startActivity(ActivityA). Is that a good way of handling those navigations? How can I directly resume via code an instance of an activity? 
Or is there another way to do this in a better way?

Thanks in advance!
greetings,
faiko

Comment: I dont believe a static manager is a good way to go as if you are in activity A for too long and the system needs the resources that static manager will be garbage collected and all that info will be gone anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Your not going to be able to "cache" an activity once its off the stack.  Activities are very quick to start, Im guessing its your **database** stuff that is slowing you down.  That you *could* do something about.

In theory, if you knew the user was going to click on entries multiple times going from A -> B, you might want to just load the DB stuff into memory in Activity A, and then send it [via Parcel into B.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html)  Then when you go back to A, its still in memory, and it will be to go back to B instantly.

If you are unsure of whether this is true, try debugging it and stepping through.  You will see the activity is launched fairly quickly, but you need to identify which operations are lagging.  From your description above it is probably your database calls, but it could be other things like network calls, or other long standing calls

Comment: so actually i am working with a map and in the oncreate of my activity i am loading all the pois and overlays from database. If I understood right, than all the data that is loaded in the first onCreate of the Mapactivity should be saved in a kind of global Datahelper. When the activity is loaded again, the existing data of the Datahelper should be used in order to not load the data again.

Comment: Right, but you will have to do this in your previous activity(or Activity A), because as @Raigex says, once you hit "back", that activity is destroyed, and all its memory collected. However activity A should still have all variables still in RAM

Answer (score 0):

The life cycle of android activities makes it not possible to start a new intent but keep the old state.

You should save the state of the activity by saving the fields and restore it to this state when needed.

Comment: the fields are saved in the activity. If I could resume the activity after returning to the mainmenu, i could load all the UIs without asking the database again. But how can I resume an instance of an activity programatically?

Comment: You can't resume activities. You can only rebuild them.

Comment: If you leave an activity with the back button or finish() that activity is destroyed. It needs to be recreated.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot resume an instance of an activity in the scenario that you have posted. Because due to the android lifecycle, when you press the back button on activity B that activity is destroyed, with all its states and information.

One option to get the information to persist is to extend the Application class and save the information into some variables inside the application class. Although alot of what you do even then can be garbage collected if the system needs the memory. I dont believe there is any good way to have that information persist through the activities even using Jameo's solution, if activity A is killed then if you return to Activity A from activity B then that activity is reloaded and the database access has to happen again.

Comment: Heres how it works: before you go to activity B, you load info from your DB into a local object, and put it into an arraylist. But before you go to activity B, you check to see if you have the object your looking for already in the arraylist.  If you do, you just pass it into the activity. Thus, the second time around, you will already have it

Comment: Yes that is true, but you also have to use the onSaveInstanceState which is not guaranteed to be called to save that whole arraylist. Because when you are on activity B then activity A can be destroyed by the system. I think the only sure way to have data persist between activity being killed and restarted is to save it in the intent which will usually persist unless the whole entire application is killed.

Comment: If the amount of data was extremely large, that is true.  There is no _guarantee_ that your activity will be resumed, but unless the system needs to reclaim memory, you will be ok.  I guess another option is to pass the info back by using startActivityForResult

Comment: In most cases yes that is true. But if you are running several apps at once the previous data will be removed quite quickly as I have found from personal experience. My onCreate was called quite often and I didn't have much data stored on those activities.